# How to change <div>'s width by user input using jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, here is my problem:
I have a div:

```
<div id="square"></div>
```

And an input:

```
<input type="number" id="width">
```

And this is my script:

```
var x;
        $("button").click(function(){
            x = $("#width").val();
            $("#square").attr("width", x);
        }
```

What i want to do is when the user enters a number inside the input, and then clicks a button, div's width is set to the number inside input.
Thanks!
P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/h2u7e7cb/).
You need to use `.css()` to change the style of any element.

Here is the snippet.

```js
var x;
$("button").click(function() {
  x = $("#width").val();
  $("#square").css("width", x);
});
```

```css
#square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square"></div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" id="width" />
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

YOu can try this code

```js
var x;
        $("#button").click(function(){
            x = $("#width").val();
            $("#square").css("width", x);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square" style="border:1px solid;width:10px;;height:10px"></div>
<input type="number" id="width">
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: OMG!!Thank you soo much! Actually, i had the same code as yours, but i made a syntax mistake! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

hi you need to set width in css. So try:

```
var x;
$("button").click(function(){
    x = $("#width").val();
    $("#square").css("width", x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can set an element width in jQuery in 2 ways
1. using css method       i.e  jQelement.css("width",'100px');
2. using width method      i.e  jQelement.width(100);